# Singleton is Violated or Not?

Tags: java, design-patterns

While we are creating a class using Singleton Pattern I am able to clone in the same class.
It means the Singleton Pattern rule was violated. Can any one please clarify my doubt.
My Code is:

```
class SingletonObject implements Cloneable
{
    private SingletonObject()
    {
        // no code req'd
    }

    public static SingletonObject getSingletonObject()
    {
        SingletonObject obj = null;
      if (ref == null){
          // it's ok, we can call this constructor
          ref = new SingletonObject();  

          try {
              obj = (SingletonObject)ref.clone();
            if(obj.equals(ref)){
                System.out.println("both objects are same");
            }else{
                System.out.println("both objects are not same");
            }
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }    
      return obj;
    }

    private static SingletonObject ref;
}
```

Comment: Please try to clarify your question - i can't parse it.

Comment: If you clone an object its not a Singleton.

Comment: My question is the SingletonPatter is to be provide only one instacnce per jvm,but here am creating another instance by cloning.it means singleton design pattern is violated.

Comment: @Rakesh, so it not a singleton.

Comment: If you want it to be a singleton why would you make it implement Cloneable?

Comment: I think what the OP is asking (in a somewhat roundabout fashion) is: Why is it possible to clone a singleton, if a singleton is supposed to enforce the "only one instance" rule. Interpreted like that, it's a fairly good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good observation. Your code is a good example of why many Java developers [consider `clone()` to be problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306332/use-case-for-clone):

It is a mechanism which circumvents many restrictions that you can place on the creation of objects. It can thus be used to duplicate singletons. This is (arguably) a design flaw of Java. The only solution is to not use `clone`, or not to implement a public `clone()` method in your class.

In practice it's not much of a problem, because `clone` will only work if the class explicitly implements it, which you would not do for a singleton. It's still ugly though.

Answer (score 3):

From Java SDK

> A class implements the Cloneable interface to indicate to the Object.clone() method that it is legal for that method to make a field-for-field copy of instances of that class.

From Wikipedia:

> In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a design pattern used to implement the mathematical concept of a singleton, by restricting the **instantiation of a class to one object**.

You are violating the singleton rule by using `clone()`. It will create a new instance of your singleton.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you can clone a singleton then it is no longer a singleton and the pattern is violated. In your case you could change your code to either throw an exception or delegate to `getSingletonObject` whenever `clone` is called. This would preserve the singleton pattern but would break the public interface of the class and also break the expectations of the client.

The best solution would be to not implement `Cloneable`.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably retain the Singleton nature and still have it implement `Clonable` by defining an override of the clone() method that simply returns the same instance.  But I don't see the point.

Clones and Singletons are both things that you should do only when you really need them.  And I can't imagine a reason for ever needing both in the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Cloning a Singleton does not make any sense. So once you allow cloning on a class, then this class does not implement the Singleton pattern anymore.

Your actually cloning a *class named something like Singleton* but not a Singleton. Once you've cloned the class, the *class-named-Singleton* is not a Singleton anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start with the simplest pattern which will meet your needs.

```
enum SingletonObject {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

Can you say why your singleton is any more complex than this?